How to Receive Updated Values from a Signal into a Angular Route Resolver?
I am working with Angular 17 and using the new Signals API to manage state in my application. I have a service that holds a signal for the browser title, which I want to consume in a route resolver. However, I'm facing an issue where the resolver only gets the first emitted value which is null the default value and doesn't receive subsequent updates.
Service:
import { Injectable, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CommonService {
  public browserTitle = signal<string | null>(null);
  public readonly browserTitle$ = toObservable(this.browserTitle);

  public setBrowserTitle(title: string | null): void {
    this.browserTitle.set(title);
  }
}

Details resolver:
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { CompanyService } from '../service';
import { CommonService } from '@core/services';
import { ICompanyDetailDataset } from '../models';
import { ResolveFn, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EMPTY, Observable, catchError, map } from 'rxjs';

export const companyDetailResolver: ResolveFn<Observable<ICompanyDetailDataset>> = (
    route,
    state
) => {
    const companyId = route.params['companyId'];

    const _router = inject(Router);
    const _toastr = inject(ToastrService);
    const _commonService = inject(CommonService);
    const _companyService = inject(CompanyService);

    return _companyService.fetchCompany(companyId).pipe(
        map((companyDetails) => {
            _commonService.setBrowserTitle(companyDetails.name);
            return { company_details: companyDetails };
        }),
        catchError((error: Error) => {
            _toastr.error(error.message);
            _router.navigate(['companies']);
            return EMPTY;
        })
    );
};

Title Resolver:
import { Observable, map } from 'rxjs';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { ResolveFn } from '@angular/router';
import { CommonService } from '@core/services';

export const companyUpdateTitleResolver: ResolveFn<string> = (
  route,
  state
) => {
  const _commonService = inject(CommonService);

  return _commonService.browserTitle$.pipe(
    map((title) => {
      return !title ? 'Update Company' : `Update Company: ${title}`;
    })
  );
};


Resolver, usually is a function, that executes before the component is loaded, we can have a observable, or a boolean, or an API call to complete before the component loads, but note it does not wait for new values, it resolves immediately, so you are getting this behaviour.
If you ask me companyUpdateTitleResolver is absolutely redundant, we can get the title on the first resolver itself, we can also subscribe to the changes of the signal on component load!
Make a new property which returns the computed title
import { Injectable, signal, computed } from '@angular/core';
import { toObservable } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CommonService {
  public browserTitle = signal<string | null>(null);
  public readonly browserTitle$ = toObservable(this.browserTitle);
  public fullTitle = computed(() => {
      const title = this.browserTitle();
      return !title ? 'Update Company' : `Update Company: ${title}`;
  });

  public setBrowserTitle(title: string | null): void {
    this.browserTitle.set(title);
  }
}

Then on component load we can use the data!
@Component({ ... })
export class SomeComponent {
    _commonService = inject(CommonService);
    constructor() {
        effect(() => {
             const newTitle = this._commonService.fullTitle();
             // do something with title!
        });
    }
}

